# Replace a Thread -- that has state variable -- with a Coroutine

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

To restate the title, I'm wondering if there is a way to convert the `MyThread` class below to a Kotlin Coroutine.

If you look closely, you will notice that the `MyThread` class has a property variable called `someObject` that can be modified from inside the both the `run` and the `cancel` methods. In this case `SomeObject` is completely encapsulated inside `MyThread` and I want to keep it that way. Is there a way to convert `MyThread` to a coroutine or do I already have the most elegant version of the code?

```
class MyCancellable: Thread(){
    val someObject= SomeObject()

    override fun run() {
        super.run()
        while(someObject.keepGoing){
            someObject.value++
        }
    }

    fun cancel(){
        someObject.keepGoing=false
    }
}
```

Comment: "there will be no advantage to converting this into a coroutine" -> unless you want many of the features coroutines would give you, including, but not limited to, lifecycle aware cancellation based on the scope...

Comment: Yes, I think I misread the question as being about performance.

Comment: The point I want to focus on is my ability to modify the wholly encapsulate `someObject` through another method, namely `cancel()`. That's the only reason a coroutine isn't obvious, no? Otherwise if this Thread only contained a `run` method I could very easily replace it with a coroutine.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your use case for this state. It would be useful to see how you use this class. If `someObject` is shared mutable state (which it really seems to be), there are probably better ways to organize the code with coroutines. Note that you could use the cancellation mechanism of the coroutines themselves without manual work like this as long as you make your main loop cooperative

Comment: Okay, imagine `someObject` is a `ServerSocket`. Inside the `run` method I would be calling `serverSocket.accept()` which is a blocking call. While I'm waiting to connect to the network, I may change my mind for a number of reasons, in which case I would need to call `serverSocket.close()`.

Comment: Closing a socket isn't a problem at all, because cancallations are handled by throwing an exception, so you do clean up and close or resources in the usual way  - within exception handling.

Comment: I also have problem understanding your point exactly. Coroutine does not have an object representation as thread does (well, it has `Job`, but you don't subtype it), so you can't invoke methods on a coroutine. Do you just need to store some objects one instance per coroutine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reusable coroutine is a `suspend` function where the only parameter is `CoroutineScope`, so something roughly equivalent to what you have is:

```
fun CoroutineScope.cancellableCounter() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val someObject = SomeObject()
    while (someObject.keepRunning) {
        yield()
        someObject.value++
    }
}
```

The function can be called from inside another coroutine, or it can be passed to `async` or `launch`, such as `myScope.launch(::cancellableCounter)`. The returned Job can be cancelled by calling `cancel()` on it.

But as mentioned in the comments, there may be a better way to design it depending on how SomeObject is supposed to be used.

Edit: Maybe for the ServerSocket you'd need to do something like this. I haven't tested it, so not totally sure. But I don't think you want to directly call `accept()` in a coroutine because it blocks for potentially a long time and does not cooperate with cancellation. So I'm suggesting you still need a dedicated thread. `suspendCancellableCoroutine` can bridge this to a suspend function.

```
suspend fun awaitSomeSocket(): Socket = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    val socket: ServerSocket = generateSocket()
    continuation.invokeOnCancellation { socket.close() }
    thread {
        runCatching {
            val result = socket.use(ServerSocket::accept)
            continuation.resume(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I replied to the comments: Okay, imagine `someObject` is a `ServerSocket`. Inside the `run` method I would be calling `serverSocket.accept()` which is a blocking call. While I'm waiting to connect to the network, I may change my mind for a number of reasons, in which case I would need to call `serverSocket.close()`. Cancelling a coroutine wouldn't `close()` the connection unfortunately.

Comment: `serverSocket.use { serverSocket.accept() }` - yes, it would close the socket on cancellation.

Comment: Yes, although you might not want to call `accept()` directly in a coroutine since is a long-blocking function. It would tie up a thread-pool's thread and would not cooperate with cancellation of the coroutine.

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood @salyela . I thought the concern is resources leaking, but the point is that we need to invoke `close()` in order to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a class that can start its own coroutine? That seems like the equivalent, something like:

```
class MyCancellable(private val scope: CoroutineScope) {
    private var job: Job? = null
    val someObject = SomeObject()

    fun run() {
        if (job != null) return
        job = scope.launch {
            while(someObject.keepGoing) {
                someObject.value++
            }
        }
    }

    fun cancel() {
        someObject.keepGoing = false
    }
}
```

Typically you'd do `job.cancel()` instead, and check `isActive` in the while loop - I don't think it matters here, but it might be worth doing it "properly" (and it is technically different to `someObject.keepGoing` going false for some other reason). And if you're doing that, maybe TenFour04's suggestion is better, since the only reason you need a class/object is so you can put externally visible `run` and `cancel` functions in it. If the coroutine just `run`s anyway, and you call `cancel` on the `Job` it returns, it's all good!